# What kind of matrix transformation can be in this code of mirror?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, matrix

I try to understand a code of mirror, it contains this matrix transformation:

```
matrix[0][0] = -matrix[0][0]; 
matrix[1][0] = -matrix[1][0]; 
matrix[2][0] = -matrix[2][0];
matrix[3][0] = -matrix[3][0];
```

The first think I have this is:

```
matrix.tra() matrix.scale(-1,1,1); matrix.tra()
```

But GL doesn't have commands for transpose of matrix and it's not possible to execute these commands. I want to understand how to use it.

What kind of matrix transformation can be in this code?

Below I will write more code to provide more details.

```
md3_vox_calcmat_common(tspr, dvoxa0, f, matrix); 
if (grhalfxdown10x < 0) { 
    matrix[0][0] = -matrix[0][0]; 
    matrix[1][0] = -matrix[1][0]; 
    matrix[2][0] = -matrix[2][0]; 
    matrix[3][0] = -matrix[3][0]; 
} 
matrix[0][3] = matrix[1][3] = matrix[2][3] = 0.f; 
matrix[3][3] = 1.f; 

gl.bglMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
// Let OpenGL (and perhaps hardware) handle the matrix rotation 
gl.bglLoadMatrixf(matrix);

//calcmat_common is:
mat.idt(); 
mat.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, roll); 
mat.rotate(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, pitch); 
mat.rotate(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, yaw); 
mat.scale(-1 / 16f, 1.0f, 1 / 16f); 
mat.translate(a0.y, a0.z, a0.x); 
mat.rotate(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, spriteang);
```

Comment: They are not commands of *GL* - OpenGL is a graphics standard, not a math library. Any such "commands" belong to external libraries e.g. `glu` or `glm`

Comment: Unless you use the fixed function pipeline. But I really wouldn't go for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some algebra:

```
A = I, J, K, L
    M, N, O, P
    Q, R, S, T
    U, V, W, X

C = -I,-J,-K,-L
     M, N, O, P
     Q, R, S, T
     U, V, W, X
```

Let

```
B = -1, 0, 0, 0
     0, 1, 0, 0
     0, 0, 1, 0
     0, 0, 0, 1
```

Then

```
B x A = C
```

Further:

```
C'= -I,-J,-K,-L
     M, N, O, P
     Q, R, S, T
     0, 0, 0, 1
```

Let

```
B'= -1, 0, 0, 0
     0, 1, 0, 0
     0, 0, 1, 0
     0, 0, 0, 0

D =  0, 0, 0, 0
     0, 0, 0, 0
     0, 0, 0, 0
     0, 0, 0, 1
```

Then

```
B'x A + D = C'
```